# Does systemd start a service when another service it depends on has status "start" or status "running"?

Tags: systemd

I have service A and service B. Service B depends on service A.

I want to know whether systemd will start service B whenever service A reaches status "start", or wait until service A reaches status "running"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on your configuration, which you set up in `.service` file

Comment: See also the documentation of [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BUnit%5D%20Section%20Options) which explains all the different concepts of how a unit might interact/depend with/on other units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither.  Service B will be started when service A is *ready*.  (Note that dependency is not the same as ordering.  I'm assuming in this answer that you really mean that B is *ordered after* A, since you asked about timing.)

How systemd determines that a service is ready is determined by the type of the service.  A `simple` service is ready as soon as it is running.  A `forking` service is ready when its first process has forked a child and then exited.  A `oneshot` service is ready when its processes have exited.  A `dbus` service is ready when systemd sees a specified Desktop Bus service name appear on the Desktop Bus.  A `notify` service is ready once it has used a systemd-only protocol to send a text message down a socket saying that it is ready.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- Lennart Poettering (2015). [`systemd.service`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.